# Modify USDZ file Shading texture

Tags: xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

I use a .scn file in my iOS application to make a shoe appear in 3D.
To find its true texture, I configure it Shading on Constant from SceneKit Editor.

Today, I want to bring up this shoe from Safari AR Quick Look. 
So I convert my .scn file to .usdz from XCode.

The Shading is on Physically Based. And we can observe a degradation of the texture which becomes very degraded!

[image]

From SceneKit Editor, I reconfigure the Shading of my .usdz on Constant, save the file and it doesn't work. 
It is set up again on Physically Based when I open it again…

Have you encountered this problem? 
Do you know a solution to force the writing of the .usdz file on Constant shading?

I create my 3D object from Realty Capture by inserting .jpg photos and export the Mesh as an .obj file with just the Diffuse .jpg file

Thank you for your help !